# mac os x codesign verify failed code object is not signed

Tags: macos, code-signing-certificate

I have my executable binary signed using codesign command and verify successfully on my development machine where my private key and signing certificate are in the keychain.  However when I copy my executable to my testing machine and try to do "codesign -dvvv", it returns code object is not signed.  My signing certificate is issued by VeriSign root ca.  The CA is installed on my testing machine but I am not able to verify executable.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing something.

The "Gatekeeper" code signing in Mac OS X only honors signatures which chain back to Apple's CA through developer certificates issued by Apple as part of the Mac OS X developer program. A Verisign code signing certificate is not an acceptable substitute.